# How to calculate the square of first 20 numbers in two child processes using POSIX?

Tags: c, process, subprocess, posix, child-process

How do you assign a piece of code to a process and another to another process? (Beginner)

I need to build a code using POSIX that calculates the square of the first 20
natural numbers and store the result, dividing the task between two processes:
To do this, two Child processes must be created:
• Son_1 performs the operation on odd numbers.
• Son_2 performs the operation on even numbers.
The parent process waits for the termination of the children, 'gets' the result of each child
and displays the sorted values on the screen

Would someone know how to do it?

Comment: You will probably use a pair of pipes, one for each child, and read the values written by the children on the pipes.

Comment: "child", not "son".

Comment: Why do you want to "store" the result?  If all you are doing is writing the values to stdout (what is a "screen"; don't think of stdout as anything other than a stream of data.  It may be connected to a tty or some other physical device, but you shouldn't think about that detail), just write the data to stdout.  There's no need to store anything after the data has been written.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I managed to make it. I'll drop it here in case someone ever needs it.

```
int main() {
pid_t even_pid, odd_pid;
int status;

even_pid = fork(); // Create a child process for even numbers
if (even_pid == 0) {
    // Child process for even numbers
    for (int i = 2; i <= 20; i += 2) {
        printf("Even: %d\n", i * i);
    }
    return 0;
}

odd_pid = fork(); // Create another child process for odd numbers
if (odd_pid == 0) {
    // Child process for odd numbers
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i += 2) {
        printf("Odd: %d\n", i * i);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Parent process waits for both child processes to finish
waitpid(odd_pid, &status, 0);
waitpid(even_pid, &status, 0);

return 0;
```

}

Thanks anyway guys!

Comment: As an exercise, you probably want to use `pipe` to send the data to the parent.  In the problem statement, "the parent process 'gets' the result of each child", but that is not happening in this solution.

Comment: One of the challenges of this type of problem is getting the output sorted in the correct order.  As written here, the output will be non-deterministic.